# I am searching a code for clearing background running apps and remove all other apps from recent apps menu

Tags: java, android

I tried a code but not able to remove app from recent app menu

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)
am.killBackgroundProcesses("com.example.admin.personalassistant");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this two permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

and then declare the ActivityManager and a List for the processes:

```
ActivityManager am;    
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes;
```

Use ActivityManager to list all process

```
am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

and list all processes

```
processes = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

You can kill now all processes with a for-loop like this:

```
 for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo: processes) {
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(processInfo.pid);
                    android.os.Process.sendSignal(processInfo.pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
                    amg.killBackgroundProcesses(processInfo.processName);
```

Comment: but getRunningAppProcesses() returns only my app